# Change color based on date value from different dataset

Tags: reporting-services

I am looking for a solution to change the color of an Expression with a lookup to a second data set.

I have the following code:

```
=Lookup(Fields!ProjectNr.Value, Fields!ProjectNr.Value, FORMAT(Fields!CreatedDate.Value,"dd-MMM") & " - " & Fields!Subject.Value, "MeestRecenteNotitie")
```

I need an expression causing the color of the text to change to Red when the CreatedDate.Value is older than 21 days. It will be Orange when the CreateDate.Value is older than 14 days. The normal color must be black.

Answer (score 0):

The code shown in your question is for the display value of the object. To change the color you need an additional expression on the font color of the object.

To add an expression to the font color click on the object you are modifying, then 
find Font --> Color in the properties pane. Click the drop down arrow and click expression in the drop down.

Then use an expression like this one to set the color.

```
=Iif(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fields!Test1.Value, Globals!ExecutionTime) >= 21, "Red", Iif(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fields!Test1.Value, Globals!ExecutionTime) >= 14, "Orange", "Black"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response.

So far I had already come out. The problem, however, is that the "CreatedDate" field comes from another Dataset called "MeestRecentieNotitie"

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following but get the error "The Color expression for the text box" Textbox23 "refers to the field" CreatedDate ". dataset scope Letters in the names of fields must use the correct case. "

```
=iif(Lookup(Fields!ProjectNr.Value, Fields!ProjectNr.Value, Fields!CreatedDate.Value, "MeestRecenteNotitie"), DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fields!CreatedDate.Value, Globals!ExecutionTime) >= 21, "Red", , Iif(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fields!CreatedDate.Value, Globals!ExecutionTime) >= 14, "Orange", "Black"))
```